# Combining DirectX 9 and DirectX 11 rendering in one application

Tags: c++, rendering, directx-11, directx-9

I'm currently developing a renderer in C++ for a games company I work for and I'm restricted to using DirectX 9 libraries.  This is because the target hardware our games run on on requires our games to create and use a Dx9 device that they can hook in to via a dll in order to do some custom drawing of overlays over our games.

The frustrating thing is the hardware is capable of running DirectX 11 (which we've tried and tested) but because our hardware provider won't update the dll that draws the overlays we're stuck with using a Dx9 device, which we can't even upgrade to an extended device, and this limits the things we can do with respect to shaders and other improvements that Dx11 brings.

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a Dx11 and Dx9 device running side by side in the same application with the Dx11 device doing all the behind the scenes work whilst using the Dx9 device to present the render target of the Dx11 pipeline.  That way we could implement Dx11 shaders but still have a Dx9 device doing the "drawing" to screen that the third party dll could still hook in to and draw overlays over?  I was thinking something like setting a Dx9 device texture as a render target to the Dx11 pipeline but I'm not sure thats even possible?

Any feedback, comments or advice on whether these ideas would be possible or if there are any alternatives that I'm not thinking of would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question - is the reason that are leveraging DX9 APIs (eg. GetBackbuffer()) and target to a DX9 Surface?   

Even if you get both the DX9 and the DX11 devices to be created, you still need to convert the DX11 resource back to a DX9 resource in a timely manner.  At the least, you wouldn't need to create the swapchain on the DX 11 device as you could target a texture but the time taken to move the graphical data from texture to DX9 surface maybe a challenge.

Comment: We're forced to use a Dx9 device due to the third party hook in to our games which draws overlays.  We've tried using Dx11 and Dx9Ex devices and neither work.  I've not got access to the hook code so can't say for certain why.  The only solution I can think of is like you say rendering to a target through Dx11 then copying that texture to a Dx9 surface and presenting that, not sure how efficient that can be made though?